# Depends: libgl1 (= 1.3.1-1) but 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 is installed

Tags: package-management, dependencies, c++

Trying to compile a simple c++ assignment, and it informed me that GL/glu.h doesn't exist. Searching around led me to believe that I need at least 3 or 4 of these packages:
libgl-dev , libgl1, libgl1-dev, libglu-dev , libglx , libglx0 , libglu1-mesa-dev , and so on and so on.

`sudo aptitude install libglu-dev`

gave me this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgles-dev : Depends: libgles2 (= 1.3.1-1) but 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 is installed
 libglx-dev : Depends: libglx0 (= 1.3.1-1) but 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 is installed
 libopengl0 : Depends: libglvnd0 (= 1.3.1-1) but 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 is installed
 libgles1 : Depends: libglvnd0 (= 1.3.1-1) but 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 is installed
 libegl-dev : Depends: libegl1 (= 1.3.1-1) but 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 is installed
 libglvnd-dev : Depends: libglvnd0 (= 1.3.1-1) but 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 is installed
 libgl-dev : Depends: libgl1 (= 1.3.1-1) but 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 is installed
```

Those look like the same versions of those libs, but with "ubuntu..." added onto the end.

Can I somehow tell the system that the installed
`libgl1 is already the newest version (1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1).`
satisfies the dependency for libgl-dev ?

per a comment below i did
`sudo apt install --fix-missing`
output:
`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

UPDATE:
I was able to "resolve" this by dismissing ('n') the first recommendation from aptitude and accepting the second one:

```
     Downgrade the following packages:                                 
1)     libegl1 [1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 (now) -> 1.3.1-1 (focal)]       
2)     libgl1 [1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 (now) -> 1.3.1-1 (focal)]        
3)     libgl1:i386 [1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 (now) -> 1.3.1-1 (focal)]   
4)     libgles2 [1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 (now) -> 1.3.1-1 (focal)]      
5)     libglvnd0 [1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 (now) -> 1.3.1-1 (focal)]     
6)     libglvnd0:i386 [1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 (now) -> 1.3.1-1 (focal)]
7)     libglx0 [1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 (now) -> 1.3.1-1 (focal)]       
8)     libglx0:i386 [1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 (now) -> 1.3.1-1 (focal)]
```

The fatal error has gone away (the package still has a bunch of unrelated errors, but that'll be another day)

Comment: Have you updated your system recently?

Comment: ... run `sudo apt update` then try again

Comment: apt update did not help
Yes, the system updated a few days ago, and I restarted yesterday.

Comment: I'm running 20.04 as well, but my version of libgl-dev is `1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1`

Comment: Can you attempt to run `sudo apt install --fix-missing` and append any output from that command to your question?

Comment: Additionally, I think your install command perhaps should be `sudo apt install libglu1-mesa-dev`

Comment: apt installing libglu1-mesa-dev yields the same problem

Comment: Odd - I don't use aptitude much myself, and its not clear to me without setting it up, what it's installing.